# Coding practice to convert string variables to actual types

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have a service that validates the user input. So, in other layers I am just using the below statement to get the amount value assuming that it is already validated.

But while writing unit test cases, I realized this is failing. So, my question is do we need to ALWAYS try to parse the values whenever string values needs to be converted to actual types.

```
var amountValue = Convert.ToDecimal(string.Format("{0}.{1}", view.amount, view.fraction))
```

Comment: I can't think of a case where you wouldn't. If you need a "Decimal" type and you have a String, you'll need to use Convert.ToDecimal, Decimal.TryParse, Decimal.Parse, or something similar.

Comment: Your unit test coverage should cover both the case where the String fails to parse and the case where the string can be correctly parsed.

Comment: Just curious, why can't you use   var amountValue = view.amount + view.fraction; ?

Comment: Are `view.amount` and `view.fraction` both defined as `string`s?  `int`s?

Comment: My doubt is whether to use TryParse or Convert.ToDecimal

Comment: If you know the input will always be a decimal, use `ToDecimal`. If you don't, use `TryParse`. It's up to you.

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal calls Parse (so an exception is thrown if it fails) use try parse if you want to handle the failure yoursefl.

Comment: Amount and fractions are two seperate text boxes. If I do amount+fraction it will be total value.

Comment: @48klocs, they are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse strings because that's what you actually want to do.

A **type conversion** is something different than parsing.

Imagine a case where in the US you separate decimals with a dot `.` and in EU you'd use a comma `,`. You can't really know how the locale separates decimals and whatnot (especially dates are crucial and should be PARSED no CONVERTED).

That said, the rule *user input => parse* is quite straight forward.

Comment: Even it is taken care in the validation layer, do you recommend to always TryParse down the layers where we are using these conversions. Please confirm.

Comment: No, absolutely not! Parsing and rendering pertain to the UI layer. Lower layers have no notion of the UI and should not have the responsibility to parse or render data. They should just process that data. Also, you want to parse and filter (validation/security) early. When it gets to lower layers you might already have done unnecessary processing.

Comment: Validation should occur after parsing. You can't know if validation of a field depends on other fields, so you need to first parse **ALL** data before you validate any of it. If you use clean stages it's pretty simple: parse -> validate -> process.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a convert method based on generics:

```
public static void Convert<T>(string text, out T value, CultureInfo culture) where T : IConvertible
{
    if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
    {
        value = (T) Enum.Parse(typeof (T), text, true);
    }
    else
    {
        value = (T)System.Convert.ChangeType(text, typeof(T), culture);
    }
}
```